# arabic messages with postman received as '???????'

Tags: json, character-encoding, postman, infobip, infobip-api

I need to send an Arabic message with postman. I recieve the text as ??????? instead of arabic characters.

here's the body of my request in postman :

```
{
"authentication": {
    "username": "myusernam",
    "password": "mypassword"
},
"messages": {
    "sender": "Mysender",
    "text": "رأيكم يهمنا. المرجو تنقيط جودة استفدتم منها عبر الرابط التالي: ht
    "recipients": [
        {
            "gsm": "21260000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

and here are the headers that I have included:

Content-Type : application/json; charset = utf-8
Accept       : application/json; charset = utf-8

[image: here's a capture of postman]

Comment: Not sure what your body is supposed to be but `"text": "رأيكم يهمنا. المرجو تنقيط جودة استفدتم منها عبر الرابط التالي: ht` looks invalid. `"text": "رأيكم يهمنا. المرجو تنقيط جودة استفدتم منها عبر الرابط التالي",` would remove that error you see in the sandbox. As for the character encoding, what's receiving the message?

Comment: hello @Danny  my text should be something like that :
"text": "رأيكم يهمنا. المرجو تنقيط جودة استفدتم منها عبر الرابط التالي: http:// myurl.com "
 I just made it short. another thing is that i'm calling infobip service ans i guess that's why arabic messages aren't supported ?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
value = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(value);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).